# Using a variable in a loop as the object property

Tags: javascript

Hopefully this is pretty simple.. example below:

```
 var myArray = [{color:"red",name:"1"},{color:"blue",name:"2"},{color:"green",name:"3"},{color:orange,name:4},{color:"yellow",name:"5"}];

 for (i=0; i<myArray.length; i++){
      if (myArray[i].color == "red"){
           console.log ("yep");
      }
 }
```

This of course works fine, but what if I want to exchange "color" with a variable:

```
 var myArray = [{color:"red",name:"1"},{color:"blue",name:"2"},{color:"green",name:"3"},{color:orange,name:4},{color:"yellow",name:"5"}];

 var c = "color";

 for (i=0; i<myArray.length; i++){
      if (myArray[i].c == "red"){
           console.log ("yep");
      }
 }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript property access: dot notation vs. brackets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968406/javascript-property-access-dot-notation-vs-brackets)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `[]` notation to access a variable field:

```
let c = 'color';
for (i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
  if (myArray[i][c] === 'red'){
    console.log('yep');
  }
}
```

More on the two methods [here](https://codeburst.io/javascript-quickie-dot-notation-vs-bracket-notation-333641c0f781)

Comment: Sigh,  I knew that was the right track.. i was trying it with brackets with a dot between them... thanks for the fast response!

Answer (score 0):

Then you'll need to use bracket notation instead of dot notation:

```js
var myArray = [{color:"red",name:"1"},{color:"blue",name:"2"},{color:"green",name:"3"},{color:"orange",name:4},{color:"yellow",name:"5"}];

var c = "color";

for (i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
  if (myArray[i][c] == "red") {
    console.log("yep");
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, absolutely correct answer but missed the correct by one minute :/  Really appreciate it though.